# Vagrant execution errors while ansible molecule testing

Tags: ansible, vagrant, molecule

I am getting below error (/bin/sh: nslookup: command not found  ) when i am using vagrant for ansible code testing using molecule testig

```
TASK [Query nslookup own domain] ***********************************************
fatal: [ vagrant01 ]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "nslookup `hostname --fqdn`", "delta": "0:00:00.012528", "end": "2021-10-21 13:42:40.197574", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-10-21 13:42:40.185046", "stderr": "/bin/sh: nslookup: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: nslookup: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
PLAY RECAP
```

Answer (score 0):

so it seems `nslookup` is not installed

You can add a task to install the necessary tools

```
- name: Install nslookup
  apt:
    name: dnsutils
    state: present
```

If you are on red-hat distro you need following package

```
- name: Install nslookup
  yum:
    name: bind-utils
    state: present
```

or if you want to distribute any bistro you can add both

```
- name: Install nslookup for ubuntu
  apt:
    name: dnsutils
    state: present
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- name: Install nslookup for redhat family
  yum:
    name: bind-utils
    state: present
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
```